# how there is voltage difference across a transformer coil

Tags: voltage, transformer

Coil is just a wire winded and I dont understand how there is a voltage difference across it. Since there is no voltage difference between 2 points on a straight wire, how is there a voltage difference between 2 points of a wire winded spirally. What is explanation?

Comment: Inductance. U=L*di/dt

Comment: Following that theory inductors would not work.

Comment: Question should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: The explanation is magnetic field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since there is no voltage difference between 2 points on a straight
>   wire, how is there a voltage difference between 2 points of a wire
>   winded spirally.

At DC and with perfect wires (zero ohms) there is no steady-state voltage between two points on a wire (straight or otherwise). However, if the voltage at one end is alternating, because the wire has inductance, this allows an AC  voltage to develop across it. Spiralling wires onto a ferromagnetic core increases the inductance significantly compared to a straight wire.

Answer (score 0):

Energy is stored in the winding/metallic core of a transformer. If you impose a varying voltage across the 2 terminals, you are changing the stored energy, and you must supply external energy to make that change.